# Export and Import of Salesforce Files and Notes from one production org to another production org

Tags: files, data-export, notes, data-import

I have completed a data export of an org we acquired through the following steps:

1. In Setup, navigate to **Data Management | Data Export**
   [image]
2. Click on either **Export Now** or **Schedule Export** button, whichever button is available
3. Choose file encoding (recommendation is Unicode UTF – 8)
4. Check the box to include Salesforce Files and Document Versions
   [image]
5. Uncheck the box to replace carriage returns (i.e. new lines) with spaces
6. Uncheck **Include all data** (unless you want to export all data)
7. Check **ContentVersion** (this includes Salesforce Files and Enhanced Notes)
8. Check **Note** (if you want Classic Notes from “Notes & Attachments” related lists) - checked this just in case the had notes in the classic format
   [image]
9. Click **Save** button
10. Wait for the email that states that the Data Export is complete which contains a link to your generated export.
11. Click the link in the email
12. Download the zip files(s) that were generated
13. The zip files(s) contain .csv files for the objects exported
    [image]
14. You’ll notice a **ContentVersion** folder which contains even more files, one per ContentVersion record exported
    [image]
15. The name of these files are the ContentVersion.ID which correlates to the “Id” column in “ContentVersion.csv” file. Note: ContentVersion object is the common object that includes both Salesforce Files and Enhanced Notes. (i.e. File Type of SNOTE are for Notes)
16. For each “Id” in “ContentVersion.csv” file is then in the folder “ContentVersion” existing with a file name with the same name as the “Id” column value.

My problem is trying to understand how to import these files into our current org. We had a field on the opportunity record of the acquired org that contains the Account ID of the account in our current org we want to attach the corresponding Files and Notes to. We are using Salesforce Lightning.

I was sent to this link for uploading the Notes but completely stumped at how I map these note to the correct accounts.

[Import Notes to the ContentNote object with Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339316&type=1&mode=1)

Any clear direction on how to complete this would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for one of the nicest, well-documented questions;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this is the `ContentDocumentLink` record that is a junction between the Object (`Account` in your case) and the `ContentDocument` (which is the parent of `ContentVersion`).  You have to reconstruct this.

***Example***:

**Source org**

```
ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId = someAccountId in source org
ContentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = some ContentDocument parent of 
                                        one or more versions of a ContentVersion
```

**Target org (you have to build this)**

```
ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId = someAccountId in target org
ContentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = some ContentDocument parent of 
                                        imported ContentVersion
```

When I have done this in the past (and it was an unpleasant experience requiring a lot of concentration), I ended up using a spreadsheet tool to do the correlation. Others have used MySQL or MS Access to keep track of the correlation.

Remember that the Ids of the source org will never be the same as the Ids in the target org. If you transferred accounts and opportunities already, you know this by now.  You would have had to do an xref prior to Data Loading the Opportunities to make sure that the uploaded Oppos point to the newly uploaded Accounts (and the right Accounts)

Doing the Files and Notes is no different except the schema is more complicated

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do appreciate. So, basically just doing some lookups, per se, to get the right items connected together? Would you happen to have a sample of the spreadsheet that you had used. I have been working on compiling my sheet via vlookups but it seems silly based on the instructions I have found to have to upload the items first then use the success file to attach them to the correct record. Is that what you had to do?

Comment: @RachelLinder - there are lots of ways to do this (the success file will certainly have the ids of the newly loaded CV in the target. But you need the CV's parent CD.  This will require a query/export.  One thing I have also done is to create custom/hidden fields in the target org to hold the source Ids. Then use data loader to include these. This makes it a bit easier when querying the target org to also fetch the corresponding source org ID.

Comment: @cropedy - again thank for such quick responses. With your help and some more digging and testing on my side I got it done. Question - is there a way for me to mark an answer as the best answer as I am new to this site and not  sure if I can?

Comment: @RachelLinder - so glad you succeeded and have no doubt said, "I'm never doing an org migration again".  Simply choose the [check mark on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark it as accepted

Comment: LOL...you are so right on the migration statement. But unfortunately we aren't done yet that was just a small piece. Tested using Sandbox.  Unfortunately now we are running into problems importing Quote Lines...woo hoo...

Comment: I should have mentioned that there is a vendor product, [Gearset](https://www.gearset.com), that has a data deployment feature that works across orgs and is aware of data dependencies. It is an add-on to their dev ops tool for day-to-day migrating of metadata/apex changes between sandboxes/source control/PROD